Is the text of speeches by foreign leaders (given to the US Congress) entered into the Congressional Record?
I'm curious what is the record-keeping practice regarding speeches by foreign leaders given to the US Congress plenum. Is the full text of these speeches by foreign leaders usually entered into the Congressional Record?

Speeches by foreign leaders can be entered into the record, but they are often given during a type of meeting which requires a request from a Member of Congress to add it in.
As an example, Prime Minister of Israel Benjamin Netanyahu recently addressed Congress during a joint session. The Congressional record for July 24 has various pages covering his speech and how it was added to the record:

H4877-2: Announced that the House of Representatives went into a recess
H4877-3: The joint meeting is announced, Netanyahu is escorted in, gives his speech, and is escorted out
H4881-1: Its purpose completed, the joint meeting is dissolved
H4881-2: The recess is ended, so normal legislation resumes
H4881-4: Alabama representative Gary Palmer requests that all the proceedings that happened during the recess be added to the Congressional record, and receives no objections. The proceedings in this case includes the full speech given by Netanyahu

The Congressional Research Service published this paper in April that includes a list of all foreign leaders who addressed Congress since 1975 and the general process they follow.
Just from a look at the last couple of speeches before Netanyahu the process was exactly the same, down to the words used to do all of the procedurual stuff about calling the recess, entering the proceedings into the record, etc.  Their speeches were also added to the record without objection:

Kishida Fumio, Prime Minister of Japan, 4/11/24: recess/joint meeting called, speech given (H2294-4), no objections to adding it to the record (H2296-3)
Isaac Herzog, President of Israel, 7/19/23: recess/joint meeting called, speech given (H3703-7), no objections to adding it to the record (H3707-3)

